# On printing webpage , it prints all the images of image slider

Tags: jquery, printing, slider, image-rotation

I have got a jquery image slider on my webpage , when i try to print that page all the  images of that slider are printed , I want to print the current slide image , how can i acheive that , Below is the website :
[Duxbury Caravans](http://duxburycaravans.tangent-design.com/Home.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your stylesheet isn't being applied on print. I've had the same problem before. Adding an explicit "print" stylesheet fixed it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="style.css">
```

Actually looking at your source, you are specifically saying `media="screen"`, so maybe changing that to `media="all"` will work too.

Comment: what should i add in the stylesheet of print

Comment: @Muhammad. Start with the same stylesheet that you're using on screen, if only to see if that is the problem, you can then tweak it however you like to look better in print. Look at my update though - it may be simpler than that.

Comment: ok let me try it , will add @media print
{
    #slideshow { display: none }
}

Comment: what if i want to print the current image .. coz now its not printing any image as I set the display to none

Comment: @Muhammad. Did you try just changing `media="screen"` to `media="all"`? And leaving your stylesheet intact?

Comment: its printing all the slides :(

Comment: its also printing all the news images ... how can i just print exact the same page which is displayed

Answer (score 1):

Probably because all images are visible on page load. The slider javascript is not executed for the print, so you're actually printing the non-js version of your page.

Show only the first image and hide the rest in CSS. Make them visible using javascript if the slider won't do that for you.

If that won't work either (can't imagine why), include only one image in your HTML, and add the rest in javascript before the image slider is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS rules for printing.

Try adding this to your CSS file:

```
@media print
{
    #slideshow { display: none }
}
```

Here we added a rule to hide the "slideshow" div. This rule will be applied exclusively for "print" media.

---

Your problem is bigger than a quick / simple solution can handle.

You have learned an important lesson, which is to consider the print view of the website since the beginning.

Here is an example of how to handle this issue the right way: http://www.sathyasai.org.br/mensagem/ Try seeing a print preview, and look how the website screen view differs from the print view. Both were carefully considered from the start. At the print view,all stuff like background, navigation menus, breadcrumbs, etc., are removed.

It is not a good idea to develop the whole website design without thinking about the print output. QAs you are experiencing, you will have a lot of work to get the print output as you want. You have to "redesign" it to the printer now...

Good luck!

Comment: what if i want to print the current image .. coz now its not printing any image as I set the display to none

Comment: @Muhammad Awais: I have added a solution to my answer, but I was not able to test it. Please, check if it works...

Comment: @Muhammad Awais: hey, friend, you will have a lot of work here. I have removed my previous "solution", because it did not resolve your problem.